# Problem with Claims in ASP.NET Core (user still have some claim after updating database)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm learning asp.net core and I'm stuck. I'll try to explain somehow.
Problem is with user claim. 
When I log in into website, user have, let's say Create and Delete Claim and all working.
But when THAT user changes that HE cannot Delete something, after updating database HE still can.
In database Delete is gone (which is good).
Authorization is checked by authorization attribute:

```
[Authorize(Policy="DeletePolicy")]
```

I found something what may help.

```
ClaimsPrincipal User
```

property still have both claims (Create and Delete), but when I check DB:

```
await userManager.GetClaimsAsync("user_id")
```

I get only Create Claim which is good.

My question is: what precisely is that `ClaimsPrincipal User` property and why is not updated automatically?
Do I need to update User's Claims manually?

Comment: to make a userclaim to work you need to re login the user try logout then login

Comment: I suppose that is the answer, but can I somehow to update without logout?

Comment: usually these claims are saved in session or cookie what i would do is logout and login the user from code behind itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claims are embedded in authentication cookie. It's like a snapshot of user's claims at a moment when user was signed in. Instead of putting all claims into cookie you can create `ExtraClaimsMiddleware` and put it after authentication middleware:

```
public class ExtraClaimsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExtraClaimsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context,
        YourDb db)
    {
        //get additional claims for the current user from database, cache it if you want
        var userId =  context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        var extraClaims = await db.GetExtraClaimsAsync(userId);
        foreach (var claim in extraClaims)
        {
            context.User.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim(claim.ClaimType, claim.ClaimValue));
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}

public static class ExtraClaimsMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseExtraClaims(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<ExtraClaimsMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Then in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseExtraClaims();
```

Comment: @milandjukic88 if it works for you mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly but I guess it can be solved with the [SignInManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.refreshsigninasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_SignInManager_1_RefreshSignInAsync__0_) Class.

After you deleted the claim from the database you should be able to use the “RefreshSignInAsync”-Method to update the user´s cookie.